# How to find 3G signal strength when connection is already established by pppd?

Tags: linux, networking, ppp

I want signal strength information when a pppd connection is already running. I am running pppd on an embedded Linux environment and a 3g modem manufactured by Cinterion.

I know commands from which I am able to know signal strength but when my pppd connection is running it will block `/dev/ttyUSB` and because of that I am not able to find signal strength information.

Answer (score 1):

Related newer question:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193693/why-does-my-usb-modem-produce-multiple-dev-ttyusb-files

Typically modems expose multiple ports via USB, one for a PPP session and others for AT commands.

If you plugged in the modem to Windows via USB, I would guess there would be multiple COM ports.

In Linux, I would assume there is `/dev/ttyUSB[0-3]` for example.